# Setting jython interpreter to PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse-rcp, jython, pydev, interpreter

We are developing an RCP application that is supposed to debug/run jython scripts. These scripts contain our specific annotations so we needed to create our own PythonInterpreter instance and configure it to support our modules and handlers. 
We are trying to integrate PyDev into our application in order to get the debugger, editor and what not, but are having problems when trying to set our own jython interpreter object to PyDev.

How is this supposed to be done?

From some investigation we can see that interpreter manager requires executable (jython or python). Is it possible somehow to set our object to the PyDev or somehow to extend PyDev's interpreter object and add our handlers and modules?

EDIT:

So, the problems we had are that when we tried to set jython jar as a jython interpreter programmatically, we got errors that it didn't have main class and could not be treated as an interpreter. What we did is, we found appropriate jython standalone jar that did not cause us those problems.
By setting our modules and handlers means that we kind of extended jython script capabilities programmatically to have some annotations that the interpreter is aware of. For example if we have python code:

```
@valueChangeHandler(context.controls.Blank.button_0)
def ASP1_configurePanelSettings(event):
    print "Stuff happend"
```

the interpreter is aware that the @ annotated function will be executed when some event happens. We also need to add libraries with some jar files when the interpreter is being instantiated. For instance:

```
interpreter.exec("import sys");
if (modulePaths != null && modulePaths.length > 0)
{
    final StringBuilder imports = new StringBuilder();
    for (final String modulePath : modulePaths)
        imports.append("\nsys.path.append('" + modulePath + "')");
    interpreter.exec(imports.toString());
}
```

So, to do this we need to have interpreter object at our disposal at any time. We noticed that when .py file is opened in pydev editor, a new instance of interpreter is created. Is there any way we can get this interpreter object in our code and manipulate it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure your own jython interpreter through `org.python.pydev.ui.interpreters.JythonInterpreterManager` and configure it as needed through the `org.python.pydev.ui.interpreters.AbstractInterpreterManager.setInfos(IInterpreterInfo[], Set<String>, IProgressMonitor)` method.

Comment: We have tried this (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587681/adding-python-interpreters-programmatically), though we got some problems when setting our interpreter since we are trying to set jython standalone jar instead of executable (we don't have our executable). I am not sure how to make PyDev aware that it should use PythonInterpreter objects that we are instantiating or to extend PyDev's PythonInterpreter object with our own modules and handlers.

Comment: I didn't exactly get what you mean... which problems? Also, the jython is always set as the .jar, not executable, so, I don't get what's not working nor what do you mean about your own modules and handlers.

Comment: I will extend the description with more detailed explanation.